# Selenium Unable to Locate Element by ID

Tags: python, selenium, mozilla

I'm trying to enter a username (and password) into my CC's login page.

However, Selenium is giving me the error:

> "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="username"]".

I let the page load for 5 seconds before trying to identify the username id but that isn't helping. I've also tried identifying by `xpath` and `name` with no luck. Anybody have any ideas what might be going wrong?

Here's the CC webpage I'm trying to login to.

Here's my code so far:

```
def login(url, usernameId, username, passwordId, password, submit_buttonId):
   driver.get(url)
   time.sleep(5)
   driver.find_element_by_id(usernameId).send_keys(username) #username input box not being identified
   driver.find_element_by_id(passwordId).send_keys(password)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath(submit_buttonId).click()

login(
'https://cards.barclaycardus.com/',
'username', myBarclaysUsername,
'password', myBarclaysPassword,
'loginButton'
)
```

Comment: Simple way you can change target URL to be `https://www.barclaycardus.com/servicing/home?secureLogin=`

Comment: That totally works!  I'm happy to learn about i frame's from the other posters as well though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ther is an `iframe` so you have to switch to it

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def login(url, usernameId, username, passwordId, password, submit_buttonId):
   driver.get(url)
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "login-iframe")))

   time.sleep(5)

   driver.find_element_by_id(usernameId).send_keys(username) #username input box not being identified
   driver.find_element_by_id(passwordId).send_keys(password)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath(submit_buttonId).click()

login(
'https://cards.barclaycardus.com/',
'username', myBarclaysUsername,
'password', myBarclaysPassword,
'loginButton'
)
```

Comment: This worked except I had to an extra line of code before the ifram switch:
driver.find_element_by_id('bcus-login-button').click().  
This line clicks the login button so that the box's where you enter username and password come up.

Answer (score 2):

```
<iframe id="login-iframe" title="Login" src="https://www.barclaycardus.com/servicing/authenticate/home?rnd=120231985&amp;xsessionid=FF4CC3BDD157751E5B9AF5E756D3E303" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

You have an iframe switch to it.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "login-iframe")))
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `wait.until`? See if something like this works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id('username'))
```

Comment: I haven't tried wait.until but I do let the browser load for quite some time uisng time.sleep().