# Selenium Not Finding by ID, Class, or anything else... No iframes appear to be present

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I've been looking through questions and answers like this one: [Selenium Unable to Locate Element by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744638/selenium-unable-to-locate-element-by-id)

Most elements appear inaccessible by ID or XPATH. I'm attempting to find and click the element that has the text "Add Parent":

[image]

I've tried things like:

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/main/fs-person-page//iron-pages/fs-tree-person-details//div/section/fs-tree-person-family//fs-tree-collapsable-card/fs-family-members//div[2]/section[2]/div/button[2]/span/fs-inner-html")
```

and

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//fs-inner-html[text() = 'Add Parent']")
```

(similarly, finding by ids and classes doesn't seem to be working)

They solve the solution of not being able to find an element by switching to the iframe in which the element resides. The web page in which I'm searching for elements doesn't have any iframes. Do I need to be switching to something else? How can I determine what frame-like element I should be switching to?

Thanks!

Anson

The HTML of the webpage that I'm trying to scrape can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17HABOQsY3CqPKSvMrA6977yhqUPna-mQ/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: So.... what webpage do you want to scrape? This info would be helpful.

Comment: @zx485 https://www.familysearch.org/tree/person/details/GXD4-SFX

Comment: I tried attaching the HTML that I see (you might need to be logged in to the site access the page), but there was too much. I'll post a drive link.

Comment: Instead of creating a Google Drive link, better put your effort on creating a [mcve].

Comment: @zx485 Good point! I'll work on that.

Comment: can you provide HTML details please. i am unable to access the link provided by you. its taking to google drive and nothing is appearing as its processing

Comment: @SonaliDas Okay, I just just updated it with the HTML in question.

Comment: maybe first check if you can access any `"fs-inner-html"` - it is unussual `tag` and maybe it makes problem. You could also check `driver.page_source` to see if you get HTML with this element. Maybe when you run code then it sends different tags - or JavaScript need more time to create these elements and you may need `sleep()` or something different.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//fs-inner-html[text() = 'Add Parent']")
```

xpath is that the text probably doesn't exactly equal 'Add Parent'.
There may be white-space on either side or the inside span 'to Maria Danko' is causing it to fail.

Just as a sanity check could you seen if any of these work?

```
button.add-person  //css selector
button.add-person[data-test-add-parent='']  //css selector
//fs-inner-html[contains(text(), 'Add Parent')]  //xpath
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah neither of those seem to work! Would I just search for those by pasting those in the inspect element find bar?